# How to receive data from html form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, express

As with everything I have experienced in programming, I am sure this is an easy fix and just an issue with syntax somewhere but I have been trying to get this to work for way too long.

I have created a contact form in a contact.html page. I have found many examples of how to save data from a form into a file (JSON format) but something is off in my code somewhere. This is my first experience with anything outside of Python and I'm not great with it either.

I have tried to use:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="contact">
```

and in my index.js file I have many variations of this but the most recent being:

```
app.post('/contact.html', (req, res) => {
return res.send(req.body);
console.log('Data: ', req.body,first);
});
```

I currently have a script, addData.js, which saves the form data in localStorage. I can see it when I look in a browser at Developer Tools > Application > Local Storage.

```
function onSubmit() {

    var contactData = [];
    var fName = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var lName = document.getElementById("last").value;
    var adDre = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var pho = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var eMail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var webSite = document.getElementById("website").value;
    var comm = document.getElementById("comments").value;


    var stuObj = {first:fName, last:lName, address:adDre, phone:pho, email:eMail, website:webSite, comments:comm};
    
    localStorage.contactRecord = JSON.stringify(stuObj);
    // console.log(localStorage.contactRecord);
    
    var jsonString = localStorage.getItem("contactRecord");

    var retrieveObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    // console.log(retrieveObject.email);

    return retrieveObject.email;
}
```

I made a different script in my "scripts" folder and can call the data from the above script using:

```
  var returnEmail=onSubmit();
  console.log(returnEmail);
```

I am trying to access it from my index.js which is in my root folder to use NodeMailer. The point is to get the name and e-mail address of someone who fills the form to send a "Thank you" e-mail after they submit the form.

Please be easy on me. This is my first question and I am sure I did something wrong when posting this. I have made an effort to find the answer myself but haven't found anything which matched what I am doing or could relate it to what I am trying to do.

Here is a copy of my index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static('pages'));
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'pages')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.htm'));
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/pages/contact.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    // console.log("Hello World");
});

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
    return res.send(req.body);
    console.log('Data: ', req.body.first);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your issue. Where are you stuck specifically?

Comment: Getting the name and e-mail from the form to my Nodemailer section in my main index.js file.

Comment: Your ``console.log`` after the return statement in your ``/contact`` route will never get called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action should be:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="/contact">
```

Since it appears that you are using urlencoded as your enctype (thats the default) make sure you are using something to parse it as well (server side).

You can add this (above app.post) (npm install body-parser)

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Your post on your nodejs server needs to match your action:

```
app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Data: ', req.query.first);
    return res.send(req.query);
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this alone will fix OP's issue, but this is certainly a first step.

Comment: Yeah, this question was a little broad and was missing the actual contents of the form. So there might have been problems with them using "name" vs "id" as well.

Comment: I actually have both "name" and "id"... I am guessing by the last comment, I shouldn't have both? I can post my "contact.html" cod with the complete form if it would help. I was just trying to not have a gigantic post.

Comment: Having both is fine, but you NEED name for the form data to be submitted with the post in the body/query

Comment: I do have "name".
<input type="text" name="first">

Comment: Are you still having problems with this? if not, you can accept the answer, if you still have problems just comment on this what your problems are now.

Comment: Yes, I am. I am still not seeing the data (first name or e-mail) coming back. 
Obviously I don't quite get this but in the last line should it be a  period or comma after the word body?

Comment: I have added my index.js file code in my original post. I have followed a few too many examples and am sure I am doubling up or blocking it somehow.

Comment: I edited the answer to allow you to access the query object. (you need body-parser to do this) If you want to use the req.body object instead, I can walk you through that, but this is what I like to do.

Comment: I am fine with whatever method would be better. It is saying "router is not defined" so I tried finding info on it and found a post suggesting this:
var router = express.Router()
I tried running it after that and it is still not working. I had already added bodyParser near the top of the code.

Comment: That's my bad, I copy and pasted it from one of my routers. But you are in your index file. I updated it (changed it from router to app)

Comment: Yes, I am in the index.js file. I am very confused of why it isn't working.  
There is a [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest in the console on Chrome. I don't know if that has anything to do with the issue but I am looking into it now. Otherwise, I have looked over my contact.html but it seems to be right as far as what is posted above.

Comment: Oops, the return statement was before the console.log(), that could *possibly* be the problem. I updated the answer to reflect how it should look. (if you didn't know no code is ran after return in a function)

Comment: I really appreciate your help but it is still not working. I keep getting rid of stuff I have which I think is extra and nothing is changing. I am beginning to think something is wrong with my HTML file but it seems fairly basic.  If you would like, I have posted it here.  https://jsfiddle.net/rms355/gs47nfvj/1/

Comment: Your code helped for sure, thank you very much. What was preventing everything you had shown me was on the HTML page. On submit I had an onclick and I guess you can't post data while using an onclick. I changed the script which ran in the onclick to a onsubmit and it all works! Thank you again for your help!